# access violation writing location c++ linked list

Tags: c++, list, recursion

I'm trying to write a function that takes a pointer to the head node, and then reverse the way the node links to each other using a recursion.

below is my function.

```
void reverseRec(digits *&head){
digits *temp = head;
if(temp->next = NULL){
    head = temp;
    return;
  }
reverseRec(head->next);
digits * a = temp->next;
a->next = temp;
temp->next = NULL;
}
```

and the function is called as follow:

```
int main(){
    digits * head = new digits(); // pointer that points to head of the node
    head = NULL;
    insert(head, 5, 1); 
    insert(head, 6, 2);
    insert(head, 1, 3);
    insert(head, 7, 1);
    delList(head, 1);
    reverseRec(head);
}
```

if it helps, I tried using a normal reverse function using a while loop, and it turned just fine, my code is like this:

```
void reverse(digits *&head){
    digits * prev, * current, * next;
    current = head;
    prev = NULL;
    while(current!= NULL){
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    head = prev;
}
```

I'm new to C++, I get A LOT of those 'access violation writing location' errors, and until now I don't know what it is (I usually tinker with the code until it get fixed, but I never really understand what causes this).

sorry it's really a newbie question, what are these access violation writing location error? what is wrong with my code?

Comment: try to debug the `reverseRec` function. It is not doing what you expect it will, because it does not change `head`. Start with a list of just two items to make it easier to understand what is happening.

Comment: @Wimmel why? I passed it by reference right? or the algorithm is wrong?

Comment: You do `head = temp` after `temp = head`, so that does not change `head`. After the `if` statement, you do not change `head`. So it does not change anywhere.

Comment: The first thing you do is to assign `NULL` to `temp->next`, i.e. `head->next`. Enable as many compiler warnings as possible and treat warnings as errors.

Answer (score 1):

Access violation errors occur when you try to write or read memory areas which are NOT authorized for your program. Could you please mention where are you getting this access violation error?

You are actually equation Temp->Next to NULL in your `IF()` condition . You can try changing ..

```
if(temp->next = NULL)
```

to

```
if(!temp->next)
```

And in the main(), change your head assignment.

```
head ->next= NULL;
```